# .NET Serialization getters and setters

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, xml-deserialization

I want to try a .NET deserialization example, but it seems I am not able to get the getters and setters working. This is my code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3

{
    [XmlRoot]
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string classname;
        private string name;
        private int age;
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Classname { get => classname; set => classname = value; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
        [XmlElement]
        public int Age { get=>age; set => age = value; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
            testClass.Classname = "test";
            testClass.Name = "william";
            testClass.Age = 50;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            MessageBox.Show("Test");

        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following error in the get declaration: `Not all code paths return a value`

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: You're not using the C# version that the expression-bodied getters require, [namely version 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties) - or your Visual Studio version doesn't support it.

Comment: Try like this => `public string Classname { get { return classname; } set { classname = value; } }` for all

Comment: That solved the problem @er-sho ! EPIC! Thank you very much

Comment: @aDoN, glad to hear, I added my answer below, if you found well then accept answer and upvote also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @CodeCaster, you need a minimum of C# 7.0 to work around on [**Expression-Bodied Members**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties) and your visual studio doesn't support it.

So you can upgrade your visual studio to C# 7.0 or use below with current version,

You can use

```
public string Classname
{
    get { return classname; }
    set { classname = value; }
}
```

instead of

```
public string Classname
{
    get => classname;
    set => classname = value;
}
```

And do the same for all other remaining properties in your class those are with expression-bodies.